# Real device not showing map but emulator showing correctly. How to solve this problem?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I want to show a specific location like sydney. My emulator working correctly but real device (android API level 25) not showing anything.

[image: Screenshot of emulator]
[image: Screenshot of real device]

The code was like below write this code

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
```

And google maps key is added

```
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">AIza...</string>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the [logcat output](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) of your device?

Comment: Showing 'Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure'

Comment: This is likely an [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key) problem. Are you running your app in debug mode or release mode? And is your key restricted? First try unrestricting it. Then ensure you've added the key in both google_maps_api XML files. What do you get?